# How to count basic operations of quicksort in python?

Tags: python

I want to find the basic number of operations of the quick-sort algorithm in Python. I wonder how to return the count variable.

```py
def quickSort(list, count):
    n = len(list)
    less = []
    greater = []

    if n <= 1:
        return list

    else:
        pivot = list[0]

        for x in list[1:]:
            if x <= pivot:
                less.append(x)
                count += 1

            else:
                greater.append(x)
                count += 1

    return quickSort(less, count) + [pivot] + quickSort(greater, count)
```

Comment: You don't have a valid quicksort implementation here. The first step would be to get a working quicksort without the operations count. Then modify it to include the feature to include the count of operations.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can return multiple values:

```py
return count, quickSort(less, count) + [pivot] + quickSort(greater, count)
```

This will actually create and return a tuple, but this can be automatically 'unpacked' as well:

```py
count, sorted_data = quickSort(my_list, count)
```

*(NB: It's not recommended to call a variable `list`, since that is a built-in type and might cause unexpected issues if you redefine it.)*